# Do different wall material have different insulation properties

Tags: rimworld

I am trying to find ways to build more effective freezers. I already know that creating thicker walls helps to reduce heat dissipation, but are there better materials in term of insulation? Which ones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like material type has any effect on insulation value. The only way to improve walls' insulation is to make them thicker.

A user <strike>here</strike><sup>(dead link)</sup> did a test to check how insulation worked:

> "2 Wall" means the freezer was surrounded with a double thick wall. "2 Door" means that there are 2 doors in series with each other to enter the cell, not that there are two separate entrances.
>
> **As I expected, wall material has no effect on insulation.** Also, the best insulation comes from having a double thick wall. Doors can significantly increase the heat transfer, even when not in use.
>
> This was tested on an extreme desert map in the summer. Each test cell was cooled to -20 F and steady state, then power was cut to the coolers and temp was plotted each hour.

Another thread [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/RimWorld/comments/345ki1/how_do_different_thicknesses_and_material_types/) also supports this:

> Item stats have no effect at all.
>
> However, double-thick walls will insulate better.

Comment: I'd like to add that triple-walls has a negligible or zero effect on increased insulation. I prefer to use stone walls due to the higher HP and inflammability. For the entrance to your freezer, creating an air break with two sets doors a tile apart will help decrease the heat transfer from opening and closing. Automatic doors will also decrease the heat transfer.

Comment: At least in version 1.2 (don't know about prior versions), a wood wall has an insulation value of 14.4F, whereas a steel wall has an insulation value of 5.4F. Unfortunately stone walls (marble, granite, slate, limestone, and sandstone) don't list such values... yet.